# change page status with code

Tags: pages, post-status

I am setting up a site that has online registration. Registration is only for certain months and therefore I want to create a button on the dashboard to toggle registration on/off. The way I was thinking about doing this was by just toggling the registration page to draft to close it, and to publish to open it.

So far I already created a Dashboard Widget and buttons, but I don't know where to go from there.

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_custom_dashboard_widgets');

function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() {
global $wp_meta_boxes;

wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Registration', 'custom_dashboard_help');
}

function custom_dashboard_help() {
echo '<button>Registration On</button>
<button>Registration Off</button>';
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit option on your question to update the question instead of posting an answer to the question to keep it clean. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to change the post status and information through code.

```
<?php $my_post = array('ID' => 77, 'post_title' => 'on','post_content' => 'on','post_status' => 'draft',); wp_update_post( $my_post );?>
```

Now I just need to figure out how to make it run when a button is clicked.